# how to connect asp.net Crystal report with mysql

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, crystal-reports, connection

how to connect asp.net Crystal report with mysql database. like sql server database connection .is there any connector available to do this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crystal Report - ASP.NET Forums

http://forums.asp.net/p/1391498/2978003.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the MySQL ODBC Connector. Get it from the MySQL site and create a USER DSN in the Control Panel.
NB: Crystal Reports is a 32-bit application, so get the 32-bit ODBC Connector otherwise all 64-bit Connectors will not work.
Once you are able to connect to your tables, you will have to write some code to load the datasets onto the ASPX page for the Crystal Report in your web page to get filled with data.